# WooCommerce customize product name in the order meta

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

The old version of WooCommerce used to save `Product Name + (Price)` as the product name in each order meta. But now they removed the price and just kept the name.

I'm trying to get the price back in there. So far I've been using filters such as `woocommerce_json_search_found_products`, `woocommerce_order_item_name`, etc... to add price to the product name, but that is proving to be too much work and might not be so future proof.

My next approach is to just save the correct product name in each order meta so that it is pulled in correctly on all emails, invoices, order detail pages and so on.

Any idea how to approach this problem? Just need some guidance on which hooks to use to get to this result fastest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I think I figured it out. This is the best way so far to save price to the product name. It saves it in `order_item_name` field in `woocommerce_order_items` table if anyone was interested.

```
add_action('woocommerce_new_order_item', 'woocommerce_new_order_item_add_price', 10, 3);

function woocommerce_new_order_item_add_price($item_id, $item, $order_id) {

    $item_type = $item->get_type();

    // We only want product order type
    if ($item_type == 'line_item') {
        $product = wc_get_product($item->get_product_id());
        $product_name = $product->get_name();
        $product_price = $product->get_price();
        $new_name = $product_name . ' ($' . $product_price . ')';
        $item->set_name($new_name);
        $item->save();  
    }
}
```